# Where or how should I declare the global variable "dtjava"?

Tags: jsp, javafx-2

I'm attempting to following this example from the JavaFX documentation to deploy a JavaFX app in HTML: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm#FBJHIEAG.  The problem I'm having is that NetBeans highlights the dtjava elements, and displays the error message 'The global variable "dtjava" is not declared.'.  The page itself loads, but I get "JavaFX application could not launch due to system configuration", which I'm assuming relates back to the "dtjava" issue.

Where or how should I declare the global variable "dtjava", to resolve the error?

Comment: Looks like you need to include `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></script>` in your HTML/JSP page. Make sure you can access to this JavaScript from your PC though.

Comment: I did include the script tag you mentioned.  Except for the id and url, I copied the code right out of the example.  I'm not sure if I have access to the script from my machine, though, so that might be the issue.